# React component works on local but not on NPM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, components

I make a component locally but i want to upload to npm, i already upload components to npm but it seems this doesnt work it throw the next:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

this is my code i have on local and running well, and is the seme code i have on npm and doesnt work:

```
import { isNil } from 'lodash';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

const MovablePopover = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {props.isVisible === true ? (
        <Draggable
        onStop={()=>{
        props.onStopPopoverMovement();
        }}
        onStart={()=>{
            props.onStartPopoverMovement();
        }}
        >
          <div        
            className={`react-draggable ${props.moveTo === "left" ? "animated-moveto-left" : 
            props.moveTo === "right" ? "animated-moveto-right" : 
            props.moveTo === "down" ? "animated-moveto-down" :
            props.moveTo === "up" ? "animated-moveto-up" : null
             }`}
            id={props.popoverId}
            style={{
              cursor: 'move',
              visibility: 'visible',
              width: '30rem',
              position: 'fixed',
              borderRadius: '1rem',
              border: '1px solid black',
              backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
              padding: '.5rem',
              zIndex: props.zIndex,
              top: props.topPosition,
              right: props.rightPosition,
            }}
          >
            {props.content}
          </div>
        </Draggable>
      ) : null}
    </div>   ); };

const defaultProps = {   topPosition: '75px',   rightPosition: '100px',   zIndex: '1030',   moveTo: 'left',   backgroundColor: 'white',   onStartPopoverMovement: () => {},   onStopPopoverMovement: () => {},   id: 'movable-popover', };

MovablePopover.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default MovablePopover;
```

i already do something like this to, beacause i think it was a problem with the other component "Draggable"

```
return(<div>some example</div>)
```

but it doesnt work.
I aprecciate your help ^^

Comment: I don't use react, but I can tell you that `return( <div>...` is definitely not valid js. Are you using typescript or some jsx file locally? Looks like transpile isn't happening...

Comment: in react is valid syntax OmO

Comment: Locally it is. Not when it gets to the browser. It's just js at that point. Hence the need for a bundle/transpolation process

Comment: @OscarDelta Is the issue still persist or resolved? If not check this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-heisenberg-qi4bk?file=/src/MovablePopover.jsx